# Is the compilation done on Titanium's server?

Tags: compilation, titanium

I have just started using Titanium and was wondering if the apps I develop would be sent to Titanium server for compiling? Can anybody clarify? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to compile the apps on any of the Titanium servers. You can compile the apps from within Titanium Studio. When testing the app on the device, Titanium Studio automatically generates the ipa file and apk file for respective platforms

**Edit:**

Using Titanium, developers can create an application writing Javascript and calling Titanium's APIs. The Javascript is then interpreted at runtime. The application's UI then becomes completely native. There is no web UI in your app since the native Titanium APIs take over control of all UI needs. Titanium runs application's JavaScript using one of two JavaScript interpreters' JavaScriptCore on iOS (the interpreter used by Webkit) and Mozilla Rhino on Android.

The Javascript calls to the Titanium API are mapped to native code in the Titanium framework and generate native components. Events in those components are sent back to the code in Javascript where we can handle them

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sapan. But what I meant was "Does Titanium internally compile the code on its server or not?"..What is running behind the scenes?

Comment: Titanium doesn't compile the code on a server. The javascript files that you write are added as resources to your mobile application and then Titanium interprets the javascript at runtime and creates corresponding native elements accordingly